# Javascript is only allowing one if statement, and no else if/else

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use an if, else if, else statement, but it doesn't seem to work once I add the else if or else. If I just use the if statement, everything works just fine, but once I add the else if or else, it stops working.

```
var portAnswer = "";
var strQuestion = "Did you make it to port on time?";
var strDefault = "Yes/No";
portAnswer = prompt(strQuestion, strDefault);

var strMessage;

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (portAnswer == "yes") {
    strMessage = "Arghh, you are awarded extra doubloons!";
  } else if (portAnswer == "no") {
    strMessage = "Arggh, walk that there plank!");
  } else {
    strMessage = "Arggh, I don't understand!");
  }

  var strOutput = document.getElementById("promptParagraph");
  strOutput.textContent = strMessage;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean, "stops working"?

Comment: That bit of code will run as soon as the page is loaded, with `portAnswer` being an empty string.  Are you trying to run it later, after something has happened?

Comment: You seem to have syntax errors in your code. Check the console.

Comment: Before the actual page loads, a prompt comes up where you can enter in yes or no. Once you do so and hit enter, it will take you to the page where the message will appear. If I just use the if statement and type in yes and hit enter, it will load the message in the <div></div> section of the html page. If I try to add the else if and else, the prompt won't even come up, it will just go straight to the page and the <div></div> will be blank.

Comment: Specifically those stray `)` characters at the end of a couple of those statements should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra end parentheses that are showing up as errors in your JavaScript console:

```
  if (portAnswer == "yes") {
    strMessage = "Arghh, you are awarded extra doubloons!";
  } else if (portAnswer == "no") {
    strMessage = "Arggh, walk that there plank!";
  } else {
    strMessage = "Arggh, I don't understand!";
  }
```

Comment: Oh lord, I feel so stupid. Thank you very much. What a punt!